# Regex : search strings extending on exact number of lines

Tags: java, regex, full-text-search, eclipse-kepler

I want to search for strings like :

```
cast('"
                        + object.method()
                        + "' as datetime
```

The code block above can be in just one line or two lines So the followings expressions :

```
cast('" + object.method()+"' as datetime
```

or

```
cast('"
                            + object.method()+ "' as datetime
```

are good matches too.

So I used as regex pattern the following expression :

```
(?s)(?i)cast.*?datetime
```

But the strings I want to match should not exceed  **3 lines**
How can I express this condition in the regex pattern ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the regex

```
cast([^\n]+\n){0,2}.*datetime
```

Example : http://regex101.com/r/hQ9xT1/1

- `[^\n]+\n` matches anything other than `\n` followed by `\n`
- `{0,2}` quantifier quantifies the expression **maximum** 2 times, That is it matches 2 lines
- `.*` matches anthing on the last line
- `datetime` matches `datetime`

Comment: logically it's a valid regex But I don't know why Eclipse is giving no results. Also, please take a look at my question I've edited it :)

Comment: Illegal repetition near index 15 :/

Comment: for some reason this gives no result !! But @vks answer gives the matches I'm looking for

Comment: Well this pattern in your answer gives only 4 matches while vks' one gives 234

Comment: I think you want to say the opposite thing. since when you replaced // by / this worked. the java tag was there since the begining :) thanks for the demo on regex101

Comment: @mounaim Yeah i noticed the java tag at the begining. In java regex we cannot write `\n`, we need to escape it as `\\n` That was the only reason i wrote `\\n` at the first place. Any ways I am glad that I could correct it Cheers !!! :D

Answer (score 2):

```
cast[^\n]+\n[^\n]+\n[^\n]*datetime
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ9xT1/2

Edit:

Use

```
cast([^\n]+\n){0,2}[^\n]*datetime
```

If you want to match `1` to `3` lines.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ9xT1/4

Answer (score 1):

`cast(.+([\n])?){1,3}datetime`

match `cast` once*

match any group of characters (min of 1) followed by 0 or 1 new lines `(.+([\n])?)`

match the above group at least once, but no more than 3 times `{1,3}`

match the word `datetime` once*

*whilst I have indicated "match once" I mean a literal match in respect of the pattern, if you have the global modifier in use this expression will allow multiple matches of the above search pattern within your text.